# Fall asleep vs feel asleep

Tags: meaning

Please, tell me the difference between:

> Fall asleep

vs

> feel asleep

Comment: Please look up *fall asleep* and *sleepy* in a dictionary (such as [this one](https://www.ldoceonline.com/)). Once you do that, you can [edit] your question to tell us if you have any remaining questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fall asleep** means to be no longer awake, it expresses the transition from *being awake* or alert to *being asleep* or inactive.

**Feel asleep** is grammatical but it is meaningless. The verb *feel* means to perceive, sense, touch or experience something, e.g. *her skin feels soft*, *we feel cold*, *they feel sad*, *I don't feel anything*, *she feels excited*.

**Feel sleepy** means to be so tired you want to go to sleep.

Most likely the OP made a spelling mistake for **fell asleep**, *fell* is the past  tense of *fall*

***fall*** asleep • ***fell*** asleep • ***fallen*** asleep

1. Present: *He falls asleep easily*
2. Past: *He soon fell asleep*
3. Present Perfect: *He has fallen asleep*